# Maven exec plugin Class Not Found Exception

Tags: maven, classnotfoundexception, classnotfound, maven-failsafe-plugin, exec-maven-plugin

when I right click on the class that has the main() method in Eclipse, and go into properties -> resource, the path to the class is this:

```
/UserRegistrationServices/src/main/java/main/Application.java
```

In my POM.xml file I have this:

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>my-execution</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>java</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>UserRegistrationServices.src.main.java.main.Application.java</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

But for some reason maven cannot find the class.

Help would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `<mainClass>` element takes a fully qualified class name. The fully qualified name of a class consists of the package and the actual name of class. In a default Maven project, the package name is relative to `src/main/java`. That means, the package of your `Application` class is `main`. You can verify that by looking at the `package` declaration in the class itself.

Therefore the `<mainClass>` value needs to be `main.Application`.

Comment: Ahh wow, that solved the problem, thanks. I thought it had to be the full path to the class and not just fully qualified class name.